# Save As Dialog not Popping Up

Tags: java, servlets, pdf-generation, document, bytearrayoutputstream

I have troubles implementing a method that generates a pdf and then shows save as dialog to choose filepath, what's wrong in my code?

```
public void generatePDF(ActionEvent ev) throws Exception{

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

    document.open();
    ...
    document.close();

    // Prepare.
    byte[] pdfData = baos.toByteArray();
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

    // Initialize response.
    response.reset(); 
    response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename=\"ResumenEjecutivo.pdf\"");

    // Write file to response.
    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
    output.write(pdfData);
    output.close();

    // Inform JSF to not take the response in hands.
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: method name should start with a lowercase letter

Comment: @steven35 method's being called and executed, that's not an issue

Answer (score 0):

To force the browser to show the download dialog, set the content type to "application/octet-stream":

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
```

If you set it to "application/pdf", some browsers will try to open the PDF inline or launch another application to view it.

You may also want to set the content length so the browser can know the file size upfront, e.g.:

```
response.setContentLength(pdfData.length());
```

Not sure if it matters, but looking at my code, it calls `output.flush()` instead of `output.close()` at the end. You may want to try that if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Still not working, i've tried everything. I think there's a problem with my facecontext maybe

Comment: How do you invoke it from the client? Make sure it is not called by an Ajax request.

Comment: <ice:commandButton
        id="generatePDF"
        value="#{msg['label.button.pdf']}"
        actionListener="#{ExpBean.generatePDF}"
        rendered="#{ExpBean.visibleButtonPDF}" />

Comment: Try with the `action` attribute instead of `actionListener`.